# List all image sizes including custom (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

This script mostly works:

```
$_wp_additional_image_sizes[$name] = array($width, $height, $crop);
$image_sizes = get_intermediate_image_sizes();
foreach ($image_sizes as $size) {
    echo $size . ' ';
    echo $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'width' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_w" ) );
    echo ' x ';
    echo $image_sizes[ $size ][ 'height' ] = intval( get_option( "{$size}_size_h" ) )  . '<br />';
}
```

The default WordPress image sizes (thumbnail, medium, large etc) show their correct dimensions.

But the problem is that custom image sizes always show their width and height as 0.

This is what is returned:

```
thumbnail 150 x 150
medium 300 x 300
medium_large 768 x 0
large 1024 x 1024
post-thumbnail 0 x 0
Custom Blog Image 0 x 0
Additional Food Image 0 x 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

PS: I've registered additional images sizes like this:

```
add_image_size( 'Custom Blog Image', 1600, 800, $crop = true );
add_image_size( 'Additional Food Image', 800, 600, $crop = true );
```

Comment: Can you show me the code, where you have register the new image size? The new image size should be registered using the following function : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_image_size/

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang - I've updated my question (at the end) to reflect that information.

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang - also if it helps to know, I've just activated WooCommerce plugin to see if the custom image sizes it uses does the same thing. And it does. Meaning that the script I posted above shows the WooCommerce custom image sizes as 0 x 0 as well.

Comment: add_image_size should be called inside the 'init' hook. Have you done that?

Comment: Yes, and I assume WooCommerce plugin has as well.

Comment: It's working when I test it.

Comment: @SagarBahadurTamang Even custom image sizes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189340/discussion-between-sagar-bahadur-tamang-and-user3256143).

Answer (score 11):

Since WP 5.3 it is enough to use this function:

```
wp_get_registered_image_subsizes();
```

Answer (score 6):

**Try this code**

this function will return all registered & default sizes with height, width

```
function your_thumbnail_sizes() {
        global $_wp_additional_image_sizes;
        $sizes = array();
        $rSizes = array();
        foreach (get_intermediate_image_sizes() as $s) {
            $sizes[$s] = array(0, 0);
            if (in_array($s, array('thumbnail', 'medium', 'medium_large', 'large'))) {
                $sizes[$s][0] = get_option($s . '_size_w');
                $sizes[$s][1] = get_option($s . '_size_h');
            }else {
                if (isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes) && isset($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]))
                    $sizes[$s] = array($_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['width'], $_wp_additional_image_sizes[$s]['height'],);
            }
        }
        foreach ($sizes as $size => $atts) {
            $rSizes[$size] = $size . ' ' . implode('x', $atts);
        }
        return $rSizes;
    }
```

**Like this**

```
Array
(
    [thumbnail] => thumbnail 150x150
    [medium] => medium 300x300
    [medium_large] => medium_large 768x0
    [large] => large 1024x1024
    [custom-size] => custom-size 220x180
)
```

Comment: this answers the OP's question best... because the OP asked for "all image sizes including default" `wp_get_additional_image_sizes()` only returns added (custom) image sizes... naturally

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
//get the image size.
$image_sizes = wp_get_additional_image_sizes();
foreach ( $image_sizes as $key => $image_size ) {
    echo "{$key} ({$image_size['width']} x {$image_size['height']})";
}
```